# Google stopped processing sitemaps daily when I resubmited all sitemaps

Tags: google-search-console

Well, I have a website with a lot of pages, with 120 sitemaps.

Google processed several sitemaps daily, but when I clicked resubmit all, on 11th September 2017, I noticed that Google does not process any site map till now (it's 17th September when this post was written).

Is that normal?

Some other points to note with the same site -

- I noticed that my website had major spam issues for several months
- Google just approved my reconsideration request which I had made some weeks ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry - Google did not stop indexing your website. (Unless you've noticed that new pages aren't being indexed even after submission, or your old ones are falling out of the index.) Submitting a sitemap is supposed to help Google crawl and hopefully index your important pages, but it doesn't mean that everything in the sitemap will be indexed, or conversely that if the page is not in the sitemap, it won't be indexed.

It's normal that Google may take several days to get to crawling your sitemaps. Sometimes they come and crawl the sitemap(s) within a day of your (re)submission in Google Search Console. Sometimes it takes several days. It depends on various factors that are up to Google's discretion. (The fact that your site was recently penalized may be a factor, though not necessarily.)

In this case, you submitted 120 sitemaps. That's a huge job for Google. Search engines have a crawl budget; they may not want to crawl all URL's of an enormous website at once. How much they crawl is up to them, but that's a good reason to include pages in the sitemap that are your most important and newest pages, specifically for a very large website.

In your case, I'd go through all the sitemaps and try to figure out if all of those pages absolutely need to be submitted/indexed. Then, make sure that all the pages you want in the index are clearly interlinked on your website via navigation, anchor text, etc. Finally, get strategic about submitting your sitemaps, if you're going to have that many: submit a couple at a time, and make sure to only submit the sitemaps that are new or have been recently updated. (That goes double if you just recovered from a penalty. A little patience will get you farther than a sitemap dump.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your info, so I will not submit all sitemaps in same time :)
Appreciated